# Is simple email address validation good enough by just checking for @

Tags: validation, email

My company has an app that currently only validates by looking for the '@' in the email address. The app is being upgraded to support other cultures and written language use-cases. I suggested using regex code from Microsoft that validates the addresses using regex. They don't see the need to use the regex version if checking for '@' works. My question here is... What pitfalls exist if the validation isn't good enough. Meaning the email server will not be able to send the emails if they have the '@' but fail other checks. What can go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The list can be quite long:

1. `1@2`
2. `do@home`
3. `why@home&not@boooom`
4. `iAm@...`
5. `@where`
6. `@homeIsaid`
7. `NoYouAreNot@home`
8. `....@......`

   and so on.

All of these are *mistakenly* valid email addresses if you only check for `@`

---

That said, it's worth mentioning coming up with an email address regex that **works** can be quite difficult. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/5198756)

Comment: My question is more about what pitfalls could there possibly be? Like is it less secure to just use ‘@‘. Does it have an impact on the infrastructure like on email servers. Thanks.

Comment: @WiredLessInTX I can't add much here as it really depends on specific applications. From a usability POV, many people would mistakenly type `name@srv,com`. Notice the comma `,` and not `.`. In this case, i would let the user know about this mistake.. Infrastructure Impact, no idea.. Sorry!